# Excluding Nodes that are unconnected

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Graph connected as:

```
           -->(D)-->(E)-->(F)
         /
(A)-->(B)
        \           
         -->(C)
```

The Graph is a tree with root = A with a directed relationship from parent to child through a :HAS_CHILD

What I want to do is to exclude nodes for a given property for instance:

```
MATCH (n:Node)
WHERE n.name <> "D"
return n
```

Which would give me the a subgraph:

```
           (E)-->(F)

(A)-->(B)
        \           
         -->(C)
```

Where E and F is not reachable from the root node. How do I exclude such subtrees?

Preferred result would be:

```
(A)-->(B)
        \           
         -->(C)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we do not have the full picture of your data and what you really want here.

My guess is that your data model is a tree. It seems to me that you're trying to define a node to exclude, which also excludes all branches beneath that node (so in your example, you may have a rich and complex subtree beneath D, and you want to exclude all of that). This assumes a directed relationship down from parents to children in your tree.

If so, you can try the following query. I'm assuming the relationship from parent to child as :HAS_CHILD, since that wasn't included in your description.

```
MATCH (excluded:Node {name: "D"})
WITH excluded
MATCH (n:Node)
WHERE n <> excluded 
AND NOT (excluded)-[:HAS_CHILD*]->(n)
RETURN n
```

Or, an alternative, which may perform better if your tree is large and the subtree beneath your excluded node is comparatively smaller than the entire tree:

```
MATCH (excludedRoot:Node {name: "D"})-[:HAS_CHILD*0..]->(excluded)
WITH COLLECT(excluded) as excludedNodes
MATCH (n:Node)
WHERE NOT n IN excludedNodes
RETURN n
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want all the nodes that are neither D nor *only connected to D*:

```
MATCH (excluded:Node {name: "D"})
MATCH (n:Node)
WHERE n <> excluded
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)--(n2:Node)
WHERE n2 <> excluded
WITH n, collect(n2) AS nodes
WHERE size(nodes) > 0
RETURN n
```

This supposes that there's only one excluded node, as it will exclude the connected nodes for each `excluded`.

Should there be more than one, this modified query should work:

```
MATCH (excluded:Node {name: "D"})
WITH collect(excluded) AS excluded
MATCH (n:Node)
WHERE NOT n IN excluded
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)--(n2:Node)
WHERE NOT n2 IN excluded
WITH n, collect(n2) AS nodes
WHERE size(nodes) > 0
RETURN n
```